# python executing nested functions

Tags: python, function, closures

I have this piece of code, and i am confused about it's execution:

```
 def makeInc(x):
     def inc(y):
         return y + x
     return inc

 inc5 = makeInc(5)
 # print inc5 --->  <function inc at 0xb721bdbc>
 inc5(12)
 # print inc5(12) gives 17
```

So, I am wondering why it makes the sum,  `x+y`, only on the second call of the function `inc5()`.
I know what a closure in python really means, but I am still confused.

I have found that piece of code in this web page:
http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html

Comment: Running the code gives me expected result of `inc5(12)` being 17.

Comment: Sorry i ment 17 , i will correct it

Comment: You only call `inc5` once in your code. The "first call" is to a completely separate function `makeInc`.

Comment: The way I see Closures are to fix faulty functions or to increment functions that need more functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers explain it well, but here's a line by line breakdown of what happens in your code

```
 def makeInc(x): # define a function makeInc that takes a variable x

     # when makeInc is executed, define a function "inc" that takes a variable y
     def inc(y):
         # when inc is executed, return the sum (where x is closed in the outer function)
         # note this is not executed when makeInc is called
         return y + x

     # don't call inc yet, just return a reference to the function itself - note there
     # are no parenthesis after inc
     return inc

 inc5 = makeInc(5) # now execute makeInc which returns a reference to the inc function 
                   # with the variable x captured by the closure

 inc5(12) # now call the result of the above which is the only place that we call inc
          # note the parenthesis to designate the function call

 # print inc5(12) gives 17
```

Central to understanding this is the concept of functions as objects. In Python you can do this:

```
>>> def test(x):
...     return x + 6
...
>>> test(1) # call test with the argument x = 1
7
>>> a = test # assign the function "test" to a new variable "a" - this is not calling test
>>> a
<function test at 0x101cfbb90> # printing a shows the original function name "test"
>>> a(1) # now call that function again with the same value for x = 1
7
```

When `makeInc` is called, it returns a reference to `inc` within which has a different function signature (taking an argument called y). The fact that they both take a single argument is not relevant.

Comment: spot on.

here's a good material too. http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Comment: Great, your second example has made it more clear now. in the first call we just assign the function inc() to the parent function makeInc(). in the second call we really do the call to the inc() function, and because this last one is aware about the previous x variable , the sum goes nicely.  I got it now

Answer (score 3):

Here are comments to what is happening.

`makeInc` is a function, which returns another function. Using closures, the returned function knows
about `x` being set to value as it was true at the moment it was created and returned.

Calling `inc2 = makeInc(5)` first makes `x` inside `makeInc` set to 5, and then creates a function
`y`. This `inc` function knows that `x` equals to 5 and will remember it as long as it lives - this is concept of closures (get in your backpack all needed variables in the environment at the moment of birth).

Calling `inc5(12)` executes `inc(12)`. Inside if this call to `inc` it adds argument `y` being 12 to the value of `x`, which the `inc5` remembers is 5, so the sum makes 17.

N.B.: Closures are used naturaly in languages like JavaScript. In Python, closures are available
too, but not used so often and some developers are considering them even evil - your question shows
very clearly, it is not trivial to understand, what is happening in the code - this goes against
"readibility counts" from Zen of Python. Also you can find some surprises related to scope and
visibility of variables. In case you do not get exactly what has happened in the code above, do
not worry, Python offers many other nice challenging structures, which you will use much more often
(list comprehension being one example).

Comment: according to your comments, i understand that in the first call of the function makeInc() we just create the the function inc(), and this last is aware about the existance of the variable x. and in the second call inc5(12) we really call the second function inc(). but how this last one take the parameter and consider it as y

Comment: @redenigma `inc5` is almost identical to `inc`, so it knows about signature having as first argument `y`. The only difference between `inc` and `inc5` is, that `inc5` remembers (in the "backpack") the environment from the time it was returned (this affects `x` value, but `y` is just an argument to be set later on at the time of call to `inc5`)

Comment: i have got the idea, i really appreciate your help

Comment: @redenigma You are welcome. I have added "N.B" comment about closures not being used in Python so often. Good luck with your brave exploration.